# jpa l2 cache co ordination using rmi

Tags: java, jpa, caching, eclipselink, cpu-cache

We use eclipselink and weblogic

We have two websphere clusters, with 2 servers in each

Right now an app in 1 cluster uses rmi to do cache-coordination to keep 2 of those servers in synch

When we add a new app in the new cluster to the mix, we will have to synch the cache 2 clusters

How do I achieve this?

Can I still use jpa cache co ordination? using rmi? jms?

should I look into using coherence as l2 cache?

I dont need highly scale-able grid configurations. All I need to make sure is that cache has no stale data

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is a sure thing to prevent stale data, so I hope you are using a form of optimistic locking where needed.  You will have to evaluate what is the better solution for your 4 server architecture, but RMI, JMS and even just turning off the second level cache where stale data cannot be tolerated are valid options and would work.  I recommend setting up simple tests that match your use cases, the expected load and evaluate if the network traffic and overhead of having to merge and maintain changes on the second level caches out weighs the cost of removing the second level cache.  For highly volitile entities, that tipping point might come sooner, in which case you might have more benifit by disabling the shared cache for that entity.

In my experience, JMS has been easier to configure for cache coordination, as it is a central point all servers can connect to, where as RMI requires each server to maintain connections to every other server.